# Is there an alternative encoding scheme to binary where similarity of pattern correlates with size of number?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, coding-theory, information-theory, binary

If I compare binary for 7

```
111
```

and binary for 8

```
1000
```

there is no correlation between these two patterns that suggests that the numbers are sequentially close to each other.

Is there a recognized, efficient encoding scheme using 1s and 0s for base ten numbers in which the more similar two patterns are, the closer the base ten numbers are?

Of course you could just have

```
1 -> 1
2 -> 11
3 -> 111
4 -> 1111
```

etc, but there must be more compact ways to do it!

Comment: "[The *reflected binary code*, also known as *Gray code* after Frank Gray, is a binary numeral system where two successive values differ in only one bit (binary digit).](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_code)"

Comment: Thank you. That is very cool. That's sort of what I'm after. Although if you change one bit on a number, while you could get the number next to it, you could also get numbers much further away. I guess I'm looking for some way of encoding proximity that's more efficient than going 1, 11, 111, 1111 etc.. You could take the log of the number and assign it to 1, 11, 111, 1111 etc, but you would still only get a resolution of the number of bits in the number. Not sure if I'm being clear here.

Comment: To get better answers you should define precisely how do you measure the similarity of patterns. Hamming distance when the strings have the same length, apparently, but what do you use, when the lengths are different? You might also say a few words about how you feel about leading zeros? Is 011 the same as 11? Anyway, the fundamental obstacle is that there will always be $n$ bit strings differing from a given string of $n$ bits in one position, but only two integers differing from a given one by $1$. So something has to give. Are we to only worry about differences in one position or...?